# How can I find the value of the first element in an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    'fruit1' => 'apple',
    'fruit2' => 'orange',
    'fruit3' => 'grape',
);
```

Is there a function that'll grab `'apple'` (the first key) from that array? Or do I have no choice but to do this?

```
function firstkey($array)
{
    for($array as $first)
    {
        return $first;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking for the first value from the associative array.  Not the first key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$firstValue = reset($array);`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php